# Copy entire content of a directory from local to remote machines in C#

Tags: c#

I tried to create a C# Windows Forms tool to copy entire content from my local machine to another machines on the domain.

The problem that most solutions to copy just file not entire directory is not working.

I can't using Impersonation to change user context and then use File.Copy() to copy content cause the users on the remote machines different than the user on my local machine.

```
using ( new Impersonator( "yourUsername", "yourDomain", "yourPassword" ) )
        {
            // The following code is executed under the impersonated user.
        }
```

Also to use File.Copy() like that:

```
File.Copy(
                @"C:\Users\user\Desktop\file.txt",
                @"\\remote\Users\user\Desktop\file.txt"
 );
```

the remote path should be a shared path, and this is not the case here as i have a credentials to servers but want to copy the directory to specific not shared location.

I found another solution that uses PSexec tool to activate listener on the server and then send files to it from my local machine (Socket programming) but it's not stable: [you can find it here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/51850/How-to-copy-files-remotely)

I also think about writing a powershell script that can do that and i run it from my C# program.

So is it another solution for doing that in a correct way, Copying entire directory/directories from local to remote machines.

Comment: You'll have to do so through the hidden `C$` share. How to log in to UNC paths is explained in many other questions.

Comment: CodeCoaster : Using the dollar sign means you have local admin privileges on both machine and using the same account.  Copying a file or directory requires the same privileges so copy the entire folder would make any differences.  The best solution is to make the destination folder a shared folder and give the shared folder the correct privilege to allow copying by a different users.  The two computers also need to be in the same group.

Comment: @jdweng in my case the business requires to copy folders to a specific not shared folder on the another machines IIS folder

Comment: @CodeCaster as jdweng said the machines having different users and i want to access folders not in the share

Comment: Then I don't know what you want. Of course just sharing the target directory is the easiest. If you don't want to use credentials that are valid for the target machine or whatever, then you'll have to implement your own samba protocol. If your question is about deploying IIS sites to remote machines, then please include that information in your question. There's many existing solutions for that.

Comment: A directory is a directory is a directory.   It doesn't make a difference what you call it, it is still a directory.  These access (path, url, ..) may be different, but it is the same physical device.  Quote Shakespeare, Never More (E. A. Poe)!!!